# Maximum number of errors while compiling with Clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

When I try to use the '-fmax-errors=n' option with `clang++` the following warning is output:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fmax-errors=2'
```

What is the clang equivalent?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The equivalent clang flag is `-ferror-limit`:

```
clang -ferror-limit=2 test.c
```